# Container of data structure: a better solution to an interview task

Tags: c++, c++11

A shipping company has a warehouse of Containers. Basically, a Container is a data structure with the following fields:

- price
- commercial campaign id
- a list of possible shipment countries (empty list allows all counties)
- internal id

The task is to implement a function taking the following parameters:

- a list of containers
- a number of containers needed
- a country of destination

The function has to return a selection of Containers with the following criteria:

- commercial campaign id should be unique with in the result
- should return containers only intended for the country of destination
- a total cost should be the maximum for a given destination country

A bonus to the solution would be to:

- add a possibility to add a selection filter (not only by country)
- a possibility to add extra fields to prioritize Containers

The code works, however: Is there anything in the code that could catch the eye of an experienced programmer? Is there a better way to approach the problem, perhaps by improving some parts of the code? What an potential employer may have not liked about this code? You see, I just want to improve and to learn from my mistakes to succeed the next time.

````
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::map<int, std::string> CountryList; // int country_code, country_name
typedef std::tuple<long, long, CountryList, long> Container; // long price, long compain_id, CountryList, long id
typedef std::multimap<long, Container, std::greater<long>> ContainerList;
typedef std::pair<long, Container> ContainerValue;
typedef ContainerList::const_iterator Iterator;
typedef std::map<long, Iterator> ResultList;

struct SearchCriteria
{
   typedef std::vector< std::function<bool(const ContainerValue & container)>> Filters;

   SearchCriteria() {}

   bool operator()(const ContainerValue & container) const
   {
      bool result = false;
      for (auto & filter : filters)
      {
         result |= filter(container);
         if (!result)
            break;
      }
      return result;
   }

   Filters filters;
};

void SelectContainers(const ContainerList & container_list, size_t places_num, int country_code)
{
   SearchCriteria s;
   // *) add a possibility to add a selection filter (not only by country)
   s.filters.push_back([country_code](const ContainerValue & container) { 
      const CountryList & cl = std::get<2>(container.second);
      // 2) should return containers only intended for the country of destination
      return !cl.size() || cl.find(country_code) != cl.end();
   });

   ResultList result;

   for (Iterator i = container_list.begin(); i != container_list.end() && result.size() < places_num; ++i )
   {
      i = std::find_if(i, container_list.end(), s);
      if (i != container_list.end())
      {
         // 1) commercial campaign id should be unique with in the result
         result.insert(std::make_pair( std::get<1>((*i).second), i));
      }
   }

   long totalSum = 0;
   auto printout = [&totalSum](const std::pair<long, Iterator> & pair) { 
    std::cout << "Compain id=" << std::get<1>(pair.second->second)
              << " Container id=" << std::get<3>(pair.second->second)
              << " Price="     << std::get<0>(pair.second->second) << std::endl;
    totalSum += std::get<0>(pair.second->second); 
    };
   // 3) a total cost should be the maximum for a given destination country
   std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), printout);
   std::cout << "Total max sum=" << totalSum << std::endl;
}
```
My `main()` function and the test data:
```
int main()
{
    //                              price,compain_id, CountryList,   id
    Container baner  = std::make_tuple(1000, 1,       CountryList{ { 643,"US" }, { 804,"UK" },{ 440,"Lithuania" } }, 100);
    Container baner2 = std::make_tuple(2000, 1,       CountryList{ { 643,"US" }, { 804,"UK" } },                     101);
    Container baner3 = std::make_tuple(3000, 2,          CountryList{ { 643,"US" }, { 112,"Mexico" } },                   102);
    Container baner4 = std::make_tuple(6000, 3,          CountryList{},                                                                       103);
    Container baner5 = std::make_tuple(4000, 4,          CountryList{ { 804,"UK" } },                                                     104);
    Container baner6 = std::make_tuple(3000, 5,          CountryList{ { 643,"US" } },                                         105);
    Container baner7 = std::make_tuple(5000, 3,          CountryList{ { 643,"US" } },                                         106);
    Container baner8 = std::make_tuple(9000, 6,          CountryList{ { 804,"UK" } },                                                   107);
    Container baner9 = std::make_tuple(5000, 7,          CountryList{},                                                                   108);

    ContainerList container_list;
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner), baner));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner2), baner2));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner3), baner3));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner4), baner4));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner5), baner5));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner6), baner6));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner7), baner7));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner8), baner8));
    container_list.insert(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(baner9), baner9));

    SelectContainers(container_list, 4, 804);

    return 0;
}
````

Output:

```
Compain id=3 Container id=103 Price=6000
Compain id=4 Container id=104 Price=4000
Compain id=6 Container id=107 Price=9000
Compain id=7 Container id=108 Price=5000
Total max sum=24000
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your post states "_I have come up with the solution, which unfortunately was unsatisfactorily for unknown reasons._" ... does that mean that the code does not work properly to the best of your knowledge? If so, the post is not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The code does work. What I meant was that employer did not make any comments on the code.

Comment: You should include the full code, otherwise it is impossible to really review it. What is the definition of container_list, etc

Comment: oops! I am very sorry, trimmed the begging while copying. Updated.

Comment: Why is it bad if your employer didn't make any comments on the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure what the interviewer thought, but here are some things that could be improved:

**1) Use appropriate data types**

CountryList is acceptable, but Container should be a class, not a tuple that requires referring to the (hopefully correct) comment to see what data get<1> is referring to.

And what is ContainerList even indexing by?  Based on the code, it appears to be the price, but I can only tell that from how it's being constructed in main.  And it's not clear why this is a multimap by price rather than a vector.

Edit: On further inspection, I see that's being used for the sorting to give the high-cost items priority.  Since this is a concern of the algorithm rather than the caller, it shouldn't be the format that's provided as a parameter - rather SelectContainers should take a vector or iterator range and then sort it internally.

Several of these typedefs are just used internally within SelectContainers, so they shouldn't be defined globally.

**2) Interface design**

SelectContainers should return a list of results that another method can print (or use in other ways), not do the printing itself.

Having flexibility via SearchCriteria doesn't help if you don't have a way for the user of the function to change it.  Make a SearchCriteria a parameter.

SearchCriteria should take the filters as a constructor parameter; the current usage where it fails everything by default until filters are added is unintuitive.

**3) Spelling and formatting**

There are a number of misspellings and inconsistent formatting.  Understandable if this was done in a short time frame, but people do judge on that.

Comment: Thank you very much! All points are taken! However, sorting `Containers` internally in the function don't you think it will be a bit expensive considering that there could be a lot of data? Is it acceptable in terms of speed? And what do you think in terms of encapsulation is having all public members in `SearchCriteria` is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand on the idea that `tuple`s are a bad way to organize data. Programming languages have decades of history of making better ways to describe data that is more readable and easier to understand. `tuple` does away with those decades of work and makes code way more confusing and harder to understand. For example, let's look at your data types:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> CountryList; // int country_code, country_name
typedef std::tuple<long, long, CountryList, long> Container; // long price, long compain_id, CountryList, long id
typedef std::multimap<long, Container, std::greater<long>> ContainerList;
typedef std::pair<long, Container> ContainerValue;
typedef ContainerList::const_iterator Iterator;
typedef std::map<long, Iterator> ResultList;
```

If you have to add a comment to explain something, you probably haven't written it clearly in the first place. What's easier to use? Your definition of `Container` or a `struct` or `class` that names the elements like this:

```
struct Container {
    long price;
    long campaign_id;
    CountryList countries;
    long id;
};
```

When you use the `struct`, you go from writing lines like this:

```
std::get<1>((*i).second)
```

to writing readable statements like this:

```
i->second.campaign_id;
```

The `i->second` is still annoying because you can't infer what value `second` refers to, but that's due to the design of `std::map` and not something you can change. But seeing the member name `campaign_id` is far clearer than figuring out what `std::get<1>()` gets.

Even when you're forced to use a `tuple` or `pair` by the standard library, you can do better than you have. For example, you have:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> CountryList; // int country_code, country_name
```

You could remove the need for the comment by making named data types:

```
using country_code = int;
using country_name = std::string;
typedef std::map<country_code, country_name> CountryList;
```

Now you don't need the comment and it's clear what the types are.

You also named something that's not a list a list. I would expect `CountryList` to be a `std::list`, or maybe a `std::vector` or `std::array`. I would probably remove the type from the name and just call it `Countries`.

What is this loop attempting to do?

```
  for (auto & filter : filters)
  {
     result |= filter(container);
     if (!result)
        break;
  }
```

Looking at it, if the first item in `filters` returns `true` it will iterate all the filters in the list of filters. But if the first item returns false, it will only iterate the first one. Is that the intent?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I can see now tuples are not something easily readable. I have used CountryList to be a map to have a faster search results in line `return !cl.size() || cl.find(country_code) != cl.end();`. However searching a `std::vector` or a `std::list` of only about 500 elements will only be slightly slower, correct? Yes, `filters` do iterate in this manner, only if all filters return `true` the search is successful. But, yes, in this case I suppose do not need `OR` operation.